# Python stand-alone HTTP server with script running support?

Tags: python, cgi, standard-library, httpserver

I'm writing an application that uses HTML pages as it's user interface - the user runs it on his computer and opens `http://localhost:8080`. After writing about a thousand lines of code implementing my own vision of MVC model, I noticed I'm pretty much trying to reinvent the wheel - RequestHandler import classes that implement do_POST and do_GET for a specified case, session handling... I've pretty much realized I'm doing it wrong.

I'd prefer to stick to the model that my Python script runs a HTTP server (most prefferably one from the standard library), because I like this architecture. The question is - is there some HTTPServer-like class that would give me an interface similar to CGI (parsing the GET URI, automatically loading the views and models) without giving me a lot of overhead? I'd prefer it to be as small and simple as possible, so if there's no standard library based solution, let it at least be pure Python.

Comment: Search for "Python micro web framework" - Flask and Bottle are good candidates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [CGI capable HTTP server](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgihttpserver.html#module-CGIHTTPServer) already baked into python - that's probably the simplest place to start.

Comment: Doesn't it have problems with redirects?

Comment: Yes, but you should be able to handle that elegantly; for instance checking for a redirect (or exception) and redirecting to [SimpleHTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html#module-SimpleHTTPServer)

Comment: Elegantly? That feels rather hacky.